# LN channel lnd + android wallet problem

Tags: lightning-network, bitcoin-wallet-app, lightning-network-daemon

I am running LN node powered by [lnd](https://github.com/LightningNetwork/lnd). Also I have installed on my phone a LN  app - Bitcoin [Lightning Wallet](http://www.lightning-wallet.com/). I opened a channel from mobile app to lnd node sucessfully (many confirmations), but I cannot request money from the mobile app with only two 'errors':

1. Receiving not yet enabled by peer (View channel details screen)
2. Can't ask for Lightning payments because your peer has not allowed receiving yet, this typically happens once a funding Bitcoin transaction gets 
   confirmations (Receive funds screen)

In lnd (lncli listchannels) i see the channel as inactive ("active": false) , but the other channels opened from lnd are active.

Could you please advise what can I do before I close the channel ? Or explain what I didn't understand? How to bring the channel to active state? My opinion is that mobile wallet is not working well, because I can't generate invoice (payment request). I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a well known problem described here: https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/issues/1347

LND team works on a fix here: https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/pull/1595

Meanwhile i'd recommend to connect to Eclair based nodes to have receiving ability, such as the recommended ACINQ node.